# Second Dto for table using hql

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I have a question concerning Hibernate and hql.  I set up a table with elements and created a xml mapping as well as a dto for it.  This works fine.   Now I need a for the same table the min and max values for most of the columns.  Therefor I created a dto with fields like minAmount etc.  I also created an hql query for this in the dao.

Just to clearify:  I have one table but two dtos I want to populate with hibernate.  The second one is more like a metadata dto.

So the question is - how do I do this.  I am stuck at the hbm.xml file and I didn't really find something on the net (propably the wrong keywords).  So if you know how to do it or have a nice little link, I 'd be very grateful.

Thanks a lot
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking probably how to embedded object into entity?

[Mapping declaration component in Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-component)

BTW: DTO shouldn't be part of entity. This is the pattern to transfer object between systems or layers. That's why you didn't find anything. More here: [Data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)